# Matrix that doesn't lose zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have a vector $\vec x$ with some entries that are zero, and I apply a linear transformation so that for some matrix $A$, $A \vec x$ = $\vec b$. I would like to find a matrix $A$ (or better yet, characterize a class of such matrices) such that $\vec b$ has zero entries everywhere that $\vec x$ does (and possibly more places). How do I do this?

One suggestion I've gotten is to set up a linear programming problem to search for matrices where, for zero-entries in $\vec x$ indexed by $k$ and any collection of constants $c_k$ on standard basis $\vec e_i$, the equation $x \cdot \sum_k c_k \vec e_k = 0$ implies $\sum_k c_k \vec e_k \cdot M \cdot x=0$, but I don't know if this would work or how to set up such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $i_1,\dots,i_r$ be the indices of $b$ which are constrained to be zero, then this is equivalent to the constraint that rows $i_1,\dots,i_r$ of $A$ are orthogonal to $x$. Assuming $x$ is not the zero vector, the set of such $A$ forms a subspace of codimension $r$ in the space of all matrices on its size.